# Is writing 5m in C# faster than 5 when decimal is required?

Tags: c#, optimization

Just a curious thought - in C++, in some situations, code can perform a fraction faster when you add the correct datatype when using a literal.

Is it the same in C#?

When I have a function requiring a decimal, lets say

```
public void Test(decimal someValue)
{
  decimal whyyy = someValue * 5.5m;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
Test(5);
```

is this performing *worse* than this:

```
Test(5m);
```

because 5 has to be converted to a decimal first (5m is already a decimal literal), so there is one more call at runtime?

Comment: The conversion should happen at compile time, so no, it should not affect performance. As always, if you feel otherwise, test it yourself. I could see the *possibility* of the compiler "forgetting" a conversion, though it's unlikely.

Comment: `5` will be converted into `5m` at *compile time*. Generated code will be *the same*.

Comment: So the answer is "No"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may impact compile time by a matter of milliseconds.  Nothing to write home about.

The better reason to use it is that it will be more immediately obvious to other developers that you're passing in a `decimal` rather than an `int`.  If I go to modify your code later I'd know immediately that it's ok for me to pass in my `decimal` variable without casting or writing another overload.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will generate completely identical code if you're just passing in constants. For instance, see [this](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayZstgBVUKMQFYJOBe2Wq16TfIVGAvkaOcS5fkJi7kYwalJh0VIjBB90qAGrvgVAlsAEgWNhCQpxc3DwB3AAsEZJgAXk9vPwDUGAAqGDUAOn0tbQY+CC8iVEKAdQAnMDQAGUhUMUTkhEMQsxMgA=) decompiled version on Try Roslyn.

```
public void M() {

    Test(5);
    Test(5m);

}

public void Test(decimal someValue)
{
    decimal whyyy = someValue * 5.5m;
    Console.WriteLine(whyyy);
}
```

Becomes:

```
public void M()
{
    this.Test(5m);
    this.Test(5m);
}
public void Test(decimal someValue)
{
    decimal value = someValue * 5.5m;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

The compiler is generally good at optimizing hard-coded constants and it'll rarely ever have to be during actual run-time.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on [tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) IL code for c#

```
using System;
public class C {   
    public void M()
    {
        A(5);
        A(5m);
    }

    public void A(decimal d)
    {
        decimal whyyy = d * 5.5m;        
    }       
}
```

is

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 25 (0x19)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
        IL_0002: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
        IL_0007: call instance void C::A(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
        IL_000c: ldarg.0
        IL_000d: ldc.i4.5
        IL_000e: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
        IL_0013: call instance void C::A(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
        IL_0018: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void A (
            valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal d
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x206a
        // Code size 19 (0x13)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.1
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 55
        IL_0003: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0004: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32, int32, int32, bool, uint8)
        IL_000c: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Multiply(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
        IL_0011: pop
        IL_0012: ret
    } // end of method C::A

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207e
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

Code for both methods are identical. So in runtime methods are the same. But it can impact compile time a bit.